# Installing windows 8 into a new partition

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-8

I've just gone through the Windows 8 upgrade process, and I am at the "Install now/Install by creating media/Install later from your desktop" stage.

I've already got a sufficiantly big, empty partition, so can someone **explain in fairly simple terms how to install onto the new partition?**

I would prefer not to burn the ISO onto a disk, it would be a lot easier if I could use a USB drive.

(I've done quite a bit of googling, but all that I can find goes into endless detain about the partitioning, and spends very little time on putting the ISO on a booteable drive. How do I do this? Do I need to empty the drive? etc?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Now: You can start the installation process right-away. It can be an upgrade (same partition) or a fresh installation (same or a different partition - your choice).

Install Media: You can insert a USB Flash drive and create a bootable USB device, using which you can install Windows 8 on any supported system, at any time.

Install Later: You can simply choose to install later.

The installation process is simple and at the same time detailed enough to help you with your Installation.

Comment: Yeah, just went for the second one, and it gives you a step by step guide (exactly what I was looking for), so that's cool